# Referencing specific attribute in another style

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to find the best way to match the text size of a label next to an EditText using xml.
I would prefer not to inherit the EditText style directly, since that would bring in a bunch of attributes I'm not interested in.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editQuantity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textUnit"
    style="@style/FontMatchingEditText"
    android:text="units"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Is there some way to refer to a specific attribute in another style?

Otherwise, would it make more sense make my own style for EditText to make sure it stays consistent with the label?

**Edit**

I was hoping there might be a theme independent way of doing it, semantically something like this:

```
<item name="android:textSize">@android:style/Widget.EditText.textAppearance.textSize</item>
```

But I'm probably overcomplicating it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your parent theme is `android:Theme.Holo.Light`.

From `\android-sdk\platforms\android-X\data\res\values\themes.xml`:

```
<style name="Theme.Holo.Light" parent="Theme.Light">
    ...
    <!-- Widget styles -->
    <item name="editTextStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.EditText</item>
```

From `\android-sdk\platforms\android-X\data\res\values\styles.xml`:

```
<style name="Widget.Holo.EditText" parent="Widget.EditText">
</style>

<style name="Widget.EditText">
    ...
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceMediumInverse</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/editTextColor</item>
</style>
```

Now you can just reuse theme attributes used for `EditText` for your `TextView`:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textUnit"
    android:textColor="?android:attr/editTextColor"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMediumInverse"
    android:text="units"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```